# Chrome Extension OnBeforeRequest not triggering unless I click the poupup button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I'm building a chrome extension which needs to redirect a script of a certain page. My background.js includes:

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function(details) {
            if (/js\example.js/.test(details.url))
                // setTimeout(requestScript(details), 0);
                return { 
                    redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("novoScript.js")
                }
        },
        {urls: ['*://*.example.com/*.js']},
        ["blocking"]
    );
```

The manifest.json includes:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
```

It works as expected, but the function only runs when I reload the page **after having clicked the popup button**. The first time I open the page in a new tab, it doesn't run. If I am in the page, and have clicked the popup button, it always works. If I haven't clicked, it doesn't matter how many times I reload, the redirect doesn't work.

I've tried erasing the whole content of popup.js, and it doesn't make a difference, so it's not because of any code there.

Also, I've checkedthe background.js file is not being ran again, so it seems that the listener is there, but it doesn't listen if I don't click the popup button. I've also added console.log to the listener function, and before I click the button it only logs calls to 'aobut:blank' url.

I'd like to allow the listener to work without clicking the popup, to avoid inconsistencies. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you reload the extension on chrome://extensions page? The behavior you describe sounds like a bug in Chrome or there's something else wrong in the code that you didn't show. FWIW you can switch to [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeNetRequest) instead.

Comment: Yes, I was reloading.

Thank you for the direction on "declarativeNetRequest", with it it's working, and it's overall a way better approach to the problem. I will write an answer with that approach to mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I was also facing this issue whenever the service worker is inactive, which as you described is inactive initially until you click on the icon. `webRequest` events are only triggering when the service worker is active, but the service worker becomes active only when an event wakes it up. what kind of logic is this, mv3 is beyond buggy, and bug reports might as well be background decorations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what was causing the problem. But an alternative approach that seems to be better overall, was pointed by @wOxxOm: [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/). With it, I applied a general rule for whenever the desired resource is requested.

## Implementation:

### manifest.json:

```
{
    ...    
    "declarative_net_request" : {
            "rule_resources" : [{
              "id": "ruleset_1",
              "enabled": true,
              "path": "redirectRules.json"
            }]
          },
     "permissions": [
          "declarativeNetRequest",
            "*://*.example.com/*"
        ],
      ...
}
```

### redirectRules.json:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {"type": "redirect", "redirect": {"extensionPath": "/novoScript.js" }},
    "condition" : {
        "urlFilter" : "js/app.*.js",
        "domains": ["example.com"],
        "resourceTypes" : ["script"]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Great that declarativeNetRequest works for you. I have the exact same issue with no available solution. And declarativeNetRequest is not an option for my use case. Is there are new discovery to this issue since?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly when you first open the page it is not triggering **onBeforeRequest**. When you trigger the page load another way then it triggers **onBeforeRequest** as expected.

You may be able to capture what you want using [onBeforeNavigate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/) instead or some combination of **onBeforeNavigate** and **onBeforeRequest**.

A certainly full-proof way to capture any tab changes would be to do something like this in your background script:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function
  (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // read changeInfo data and do something with it (like read the url)
    if (changeInfo.url && ..url-comparison-here) {
      // do something here

    }
  }
);
```

Comment: "When you trigger the page load another way" I'm not sure I understood this part. I think it's not related to page load, because only when I click the popup it works, not when I reload.

I have tried the onUpdate approach before, but couldn't get it to work because I couldn't figure a synchronous way of getting the url when changeInfo doesn't include url. But I got it to work anyway using declarativeNetRequest. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Quoting from the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#manifest) "if you require access to the url, pendingUrl, title, or favIconUrl properties of tabs.Tab, you must declare the "tabs" permission in the manifest.", But tabs permission shows the user "read your browsing history" as the permission. So I think this is a good option only if you are already requesting tabs permission but otherwise for redirecting just one domain using this `tabs` permission is unacceptable.